# restore to defaults with jQuery hover

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover

I have below code:

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#developer").hover(function() {
        $("#coder").fadeTo(1000,0.4);
        $("#my_pic").animate({right:'110px'}, 1500);
    });
});
```

It works but I want to restore defaults when user moves the mouse out of the area of `#developer`.

**CSS**

```
#coder {
    opacity: 1;
}

#my_pic {
    position: relative;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="developer" class="threecol">
    <h1><span>&lt;</span>developer<span>&gt;</span></h1>
</div>

<div class="sixcol">
    <img id="my_pic" src="images/me.png" />
</div>

<div id="coder" class="threecol last">
    <h1><span>&lt;</span>coder<span>&gt;</span></h1>
</div>
```

Comment: @Felix: The markup is too long. It is simply when I hover over #developer, the #coder fades to 0.4 and the #my_pic animates to right: 110px. It stays like that even when I mouse out of the #developer.

Comment: @Felix: I am no jQuery expert, but I believe that jQuery hover has on_mouse_in and on_mouse_out. So somehow I have to write a function for the on_mouse_out part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a 2nd `function` for `hover`

```
, function(){
    $("#coder").fadeTo(1000,1);
    $("#my_pic").animate({right:'0px'}, 500);            
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kWS3q/)**

Answer (score 0):

Just append the other function taking care of the resetting after the first function inside `hover`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#developer").hover(
        function() {
            $("#coder").fadeTo(1000,0.4);
            $("#my_pic").animate({right:'110px'}, 1500);
        }, function() {
            $("#coder").fadeTo(1000,1);
            $("#my_pic").animate({right:'0'}, 1500);
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#developer").mouseout(function() {
    $("#coder").fadeTo(1000,1);
    $("#my_pic").animate({right:'110px'}, 1500);
});
});
```

Comment: this would require to setup 2 functions... `hover` takes care of both, `mouseover` and `mouseout`... [http://api.jquery.com/hover/](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
    $("#developer").hover(function() {
        $("#coder").fadeTo(1000,0.4);
        $("#my_pic").animate({right:'110px'}, 1500);
    }, 
    function() {
        $("#coder").fadeTo(1000,1);
        $("#my_pic").animate({right:'0'}, 1500)
    });
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/TMjS3/2/)